# Laravel 4.2 behind ELB - Sessions not working

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-4, session-cookies

I'm running Laravel 4.2 with database session storage.
My application is running behind a Load Balancer.

When only one instance is running, my application works fine. 
Then if i enable a second instance my application stops working.

My application adds a session to the database on almost every pageload, and i can't write/read sessions (and can't login).

Here is my session config

```
return array(

    'driver' => 'database',

    'lifetime' => 1440,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

    'connection' => "mysql",

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'lottery' => array(2, 100),

    'cookie' => 'ycrm_session',

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' =>  null,

    'secure' =>  false,

);
```

My sessions table looks like this 
[image]

Have anybody experied that issue before?

Comment: It sounds like you have everything set up correctly. Can you confirm a few things?  1. is the cookie getting set at all when you have multiple instances?  2. Are you able to connect to the DB from all instances? 3. Is the sessions table getting populated when you have multiple instances?

Comment: Hi @swatkins ! Thanks for reaching out.
1. When running with multiple instances the cookie seems to be reset on almost every pageload.
2. Yeah, no database issues at all. 
3. Yes, the table is getting populated, but almost on every pageload. I think its doing it when swithcing between instances. 

Do you have an idea?

Comment: I also tried redis for session storage, but that seems to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. 
I'm using [forge](https://forge.laravel.com) to manage and deploy my application. When i deploy my code its running **composer install** and its seems to edit my ***config/app.php*** . 
I just redeployed my ***config/app.php*** and its starts working.